# how to find runtime error in Android Spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

I am new in Android, Below  is my code for Spinner.

And I don't get any error with this code but my app crashed when I run it.

If code contains Spinner, it crashes with "**Unfortunately App has stopped**" error.

But if i remove Spinner, it works perfectly fine.

```
 private Spinner spinner;
 private static final String[]paths = {"item 1", "item 2", "item 3"};
 @Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,paths);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener((OnItemSelectedListener) this);

}


public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
{

    switch (position) 
    {
        case 0:
        //  System.out.println("india");
            // Whatever you want to happen when the first item gets selected
            break;
        case 1:
            // Whatever you want to happen when the second item gets selected
            break;
        case 2:
            // Whatever you want to happen when the thrid item gets selected
            break;
            default:break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Post the error stack please!

Comment: change `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener((OnItemSelectedListener) this);` to `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(YouActivityName.this);` and post logcat error too.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your **onCreate** Code with the below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,paths);


    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(MainActivity.this);

}
```